Using purrr::map with a user defined function - how to pass arguments
I am creating a package where I have a function (pkgfun) that computes some indicators based on values from subsets of a data frame, using group_by and purrr::map. I would also like to let the user be able to submit an additional function (userfun) to compute this indicator, in case none of the built-in functions matches the needs. pkgfun should therefore accept some additional parameters for userfun, but also make it possible for userfun to use other variables in pkgfun, either other arguments or variables defined inside the function.
Ideally, I would have liked to write the functions as close to the following example as possible. However, this will not correctly pass the arguments.
pkgfun = function(df, pkgArg, userfun, fargs, test, ...) {
    dots = list(...)
    funArg = 3
    fargs = names(formals(userfun))
    ufRes = df %>% 
      group_by(himgid) %>%  nest() %>%
      mutate(ufres = map(data, ~userfun(., fargs))) %>%
      unnest(ufres) %>% ungroup %>% select(ufres) %>% pull 
    print("ufRes")
    ufRes
  }
  
  userfun = function(df, aboveLimit, pkgArg, funArg) {
    print(funArg)
    sum(df$gridvar > aboveLimit) >= pkgArg
  }

 pkgfun(df, userfun = userfun, aboveLimit = 5, pkgArg = 5)

I have managed to create a simplified working example, but I find it depends on a bit of redundancy on the user side, it seems a bit too complicated, and it uses some expressions I would prefer to remove (such as eval(parse(...)) ).
The implementation of pkgfun allows for two ways of passing the right arguments, but I don't like either.
The first one takes an additional argument fargs, which includes all the names of the arguments that should be added to argList, a list of arguments. This is a nuisance when calling the function.
The second one checks the list of required arguments of userfun, searches for them and adds them all to argList. However, this means the user needs to specify dummy arguments in userfun that are actually not used in the function.
I think it should be possible both to get closer to the first example and remove the eval(parse construct, but how...? Any suggestions?
# pkgArg is an argument that is otherwise used in pkgfun, and reused in userfun
pkgfun = function(df, pkgArg, userfun, fargs, test, ...) {
  dots = list(...)
# funArg is a variable defined inside the function, and but also useful in userfun. 
  funArg = 3
# Finding the arguments from userfun if not given as an argument
  if (missing(fargs)) {
    fargs = names(formals(userfun))
    fargs = fargs[!(fargs %in% c("df", "argList", "..."))]
  }
  dnames = names(dots)[which(names(dots) %in% fargs)] 
# Adding ... arguments to the environment, so they are available to dynGet
  if (length(dnames) > 0) for (dn in dnames) eval(parse(text = paste(dn, "=", dots[[dn]] )))
  argList = lapply(fargs, dynGet)
  names(argList) = fargs
# 
  ufRes = df %>%
    group_by(himgid) %>%  nest() %>%
    mutate(ufRes = map(data, ~userfun(., argList = argList))) %>%
    unnest(ufRes) %>% ungroup %>% select(ufRes) %>% pull 
  print("ufRes")
  ufRes
}

# The userfun checks if the group has at least pkgArg entries that are larger than aboveLimit
# It also prints the names of the arguments in argList, and funArg, just to check that it 
# is correctly passed
userfun = function(df, aboveLimit, pkgArg, funArg, argList) {
  print(paste("argList", names(argList)))
   aboveLimit = argList$aboveLimit
   pkgArg = argList$pkgArg
   funArg = argList$funArg
   print(funArg)
    sum(df$gridvar > aboveLimit) >= pkgArg
  }

  df = data.frame(himgid = rep(c(1,2,3), 20), gridvar = 1:20)

# Call function with a vector of argument names, the named variables are then unnecessary in
# function definition
  pkgfun(df, userfun = userfun, fargs = c("aboveLimit", "pkgArg", "pkgArg"), 
            aboveLimit = 5, pkgArg = 5)
# This call is possible when the arguments are named in the function definition
  pkgfun(df, userfun = userfun, aboveLimit = 5, pkgArg = 5)



I have added an example of the ideal (but non-working) functions at the beginning. They are closer to how I think the functions should be implemented, but something is missing. The old example is kept, to show two suboptimal ways of getting the right functionality.

I am not sure who closed this. Anyway, I will not modify the question further, as it has already received a good answer that solves the most important questions above.

I'll take a stab at it ...
require(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(himgid = rep(c(1,2,3), 20), gridvar = 1:20)


pkgfun = function(df, pkgArg, userfun, fargs, test, ...) {

  dots = list(...)
  funArg = 3
  fargs_names = names(formals(userfun))
  
  passed_in  <- setdiff(intersect(ls(),fargs_names),"df")
  names(passed_in) <- passed_in
  args_to_pass <- map(passed_in,\(x)get(x,pos = -1)) |> setNames(passed_in)
  args_to_pass <- c(args_to_pass,dots)

  ufRes = df %>% 
    group_by(himgid) %>%  nest() %>%
    mutate(ufres = map(data, \(subdata){
      local_args <- c(list("df"=subdata),args_to_pass)
      do.call(userfun,args=local_args)})) %>%
    unnest(ufres) %>% ungroup %>% select(ufres) %>% pull 
  print("ufRes")
  ufRes
}

userfun = function(df, aboveLimit, pkgArg, funArg) {
  print(funArg)
  sum(df$gridvar > aboveLimit) >= pkgArg
}

pkgfun(df, userfun = userfun, aboveLimit = 5, pkgArg = 5)


Thanks! Not an easy solution (I still have to work a bit to understand exactly how and why), but it seems to solve the two most important requirements I had compared to my solution - simplify the creation userfun for the user and remove eval(parse

one thing I did was rename limit to aboveLimit in the pkgfun call you make to test; as I didnt see how else Limit should be interpreted as being aboveLimit

Yes, you're right, that was a typo when I was simplifying the code for the example. I changed all instances of limit in the examples back to aboveLimit, so that it matches your answer.

And as I have gone through the different parts in detail, I also understand it better. Very nice! I have two questions about lines that could maybe be simplified though. Is ' names(passed_in) <- passed_in' necessary? And could the line ' args_to_pass <- map(passed_in,(x)get(x,pos = -1)) |> setNames(passed_in)' be replaced with 'args_to_pass <- map(passed_in, dynGet)'? Ignoring the names in both cases seems to work for me, but maybe I am missing something?


I did make a mistake by solving a minor detail twice, so one of the solutions is redundant; you can either remove the names(passed_in) <- passed_in or the following setnames on the map; as they are both there to acheive the same affect, so having one means dont need the other.



dynGet, code does look marginally cleaner so potentially a good shout; I guess the only thing the pos=-1 has to benefit is , is depending on it could cause you problems to find what is being searched for at some other depths (or if that could be an advantage). I suggest you write tests and satisfy yourself that you are happy; and down the road if you ever hit related bugs you have options to explore.


Super, thanks for the explanations!
